# Ignore %d in Python (MySQL)

Tags: python, mysql, insert

I am running a Python script that inserts a set of data into a MySQL table. The data is stored in a CSV and the file name and location is referred to using a variable. However, having assigned a value to this (written as '%s' in my code), Python now tries to interpret my other SQL code relating to a date later on in my code.

For example:

```
PreviousName7CONDATE = IF(@PreviousName7CONDATE = '', NULL, STR_TO_DATE(@PreviousName7CONDATE, '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

The %d, and I assume %m and also %Y as soon as the %d issue is overcome is preventing my insert script from running. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just escape literal percent signs in the query string. Assuming you use MySQLdb, the [docs](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes) suggest exactly this:

> Note that any literal percent signs in the query string passed to
>   `execute()` must be escaped, i.e. `%%`.